# How to parse this JSON result in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to read this JSON that I get as a result of an AJAX *get* function. I seem to successfully get the data since when I `console.log(result)` I get the data in the console but I cannot seem to handle this result as a JSON object.

```
var isbnURL = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:9780739332122"
$.ajax({            
    type: 'GET',
    url: isbnURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.length);
    },
    error: function(message){
        console.log(message);           
    }
});
```

I am expecting that `console.log(result.length);` returns the length and not `undefined` in the console.

Comment: A JSON of an object is returned, not a JSON of an array. Objects (almost always) do not have a `.length` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this is an object, not an array. Maybe you want to get, for example, the list of `links` inside the object. In this case you can do that:

```
result["ISBN:9780739332122"].links.length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isbnURL = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:9780739332122";

var isbnURL = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:9780739332122";

$.getJSON({
    url: isbnURL,
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        console.log("Small cover: " + value.cover.small);
        console.log("Title: " + value.title)
    });
  }
});
```

This works. `getJSON` obtains the JSON and parses it, then the `each` function loops through each book.